# Stoping threads dynamicly in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

i need some help with threads , i need to make a program that will close and open threads dynamically ( meaning when i need a thread it will run, if its no longer needed it will stop ) , 
Now my questions is? is k if i only terminate the run method of that thread , does it count as the thread stopping, or how exactly do a close a thread .

```
public void run() {
    while(!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        try {
                if(tasks.peek() != null) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    waitingPeriod.getAndAdd(-1);
                    tasks.peek().setProcessingTime(tasks.peek().getProcessingTime() - 1);
                    if(tasks.peek().getProcessingTime() == 0) {
                        // System.out.println("Removed task " + tasks.peek().getId() + " from queue" );
                        tasks.remove();
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

                        continue;

                    }
                }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {

        }
        //take next task from queue
        //stop the thread for a time equal with the task's processing time
        //decrement the waitingPeriod
    }

}
```

This threads works over a queue , if there are elements in it i start it from another class, and i want this thread to run only if i have elements, so when the queue empties i want the thread to stop.
how do i stop the thread , is enough to terminate the run function with that while?

Comment: What do you expect from the call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having a sleeping thread. Starting and stopping thread is relatively expensive. What you most likely want is to have an asynchronous condition to wake the thread up e.g. `Object.notify()`.

Comment: You seem to be making horrible mistakes.  You should probably submit tasks to the common ForkJoinPool instead of starting and stopping your own threads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html